# Filling array with data from textfile

Tags: c

I have a .txt file with double data. Each in a new line. 
I am about to read from a file two times - one to count how many numbers the file has, and two - to fill the array with data. So I did it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[30];
scanf ("%s", name);

FILE *file = fopen (name, "r");
if (!file) 
{
    printf ("Cannot read from file %s!\n", name);
    return 1;
}

double results;
int size = 0;
while ( fscanf (plik, "%lf", &results) != EOF)
{
    size++;
}
//and here I have how many numbers is in the file

double numbers[size]; 
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    fscanf (plik, "%lf\n", &numbers[i]);

}   
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%lf\n" , numbers[i]);
}
```

But it is not working - results are just 0.000000 in amount of 6510 (so many). Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is this your complete code or just snippet ? Where is your main function?

Comment: this is just snippet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a sample of how the data in your textfile looks like.

Comment: like this:
532.35 (new line)
234.13 (new line)
236.92 (new line)
etc

Comment: code pasted from two different source, unable to compile.

Comment: @beechy for clarifications please [edit] your question and don't reply in a comment where you cannot format the text.

Comment: You open the file with using `file`, but then you read from `plik`. Very unclear, post a [MCVE].

Comment: OK, once you have determined `size`, you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file using `fseek ( plik , 0 , SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: You should check the return value of `fscanf` - you'll find that in the second batch you're not reading anything in as you're already at the end of the file.

Comment: `double numbers[size];` --> `double numbers[size];rewind(plik);`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Chris, fscanf moves file pointer as you read the file in the first pass. So you're not reading anything in second pass. I'm assuming all the code is in the main function and the `plik` is just another identifier copied from `file` . Resetting the file pointer to the beginning of the file using `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET)` seemed to solve the problem for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char name[30];
  scanf ("%s", name);

  FILE *file = fopen (name, "r");
  if (!file) 
    {
      printf ("Cannot read from file %s!\n", name);
      return 1;
    }

  double results;
  int size = 0;
  FILE *pFilePtr = file;
  printf("file = %p\n", file);
  while ( fscanf (pFilePtr, "%lf", &results) != EOF) 
      size++;
  printf("size : %d\n", size);

  double numbers[size]; 
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
  FILE *plik = file;
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
      fscanf (plik, "%lf", &numbers[i]);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      printf("%lf\n" , numbers[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

I ran it assuming this file input:

```
~/Documents/src : $ cat testFile.txt 
1.2334 2.223 3.34 4.21 5.34 6.23
~/Documents/src : $ g++ testFillArr.c
~/Documents/src : $ ./a.out 
testFile.txt    
file = 0x559494bdd420
size : 6
1.233400
2.223000
3.340000
4.210000
5.340000
6.230000
```

Comment: Note that if the data in the file contains some bogus character (a letter, for example), then the initial loop will never terminate because `fscanf()` will return `0` rather than `EOF`.  Check that you got the number of conversions that you need, which is `1`: `while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &result) == 1)`.